# window.location.href(var) strange behaviour on ff7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I don't understand the issue I'm having on FF7

I have an ajax calls that return a json object (jquery).

```
if(data.result=='ok') {
    var url = baseURL + "azioni/makeForm/" + data.actcode + "/DIA/" + data.az_id;
    console.log(url);
    window.location.href(url);
}
```

Don't work at all, but this one does:

```
if(data.result=='ok') {
    var url = baseURL + "azioni/makeForm/" + data.actcode + "/DIA/" + data.az_id;
    console.log(url);
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
    window.location.href(url);
}
```

Why?

Please note that console.log works perfectly and outputs the correct url!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you might want to use:

```
document.location.href = url;
```

I think .href is not a method but a property, so you can only assign a value to it. Underneath is probably an event listerer that let's the browser redirect to that location.

Comment: Wow, I was bangin my head for a really stupid mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try:

```
if(data.result=='ok') {
                 var url = baseURL+"azioni/makeForm/"+data.actcode+"/DIA/"+data.az_id;console.log(url);
                window.location.href = url;

            }
```

Comment: As far as I know window.location.href is not a function so you don't need the ()

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` is not a function. In your second example you could simply remove `window.location.href(url)` and it would work

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` is a JavaScript property, not a jQuery method. To change URLs, you should set the `window.location` using `=`:

```
window.location = url;
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location